# Can't read asp user control parameters

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, parameters

I'm driving myself nuts with this particular problem, i really hope someone can help! In the below example i cant get the value of "4" to appear in the rendered page. The output from below compiles and executes just fine but all three of the values shown are "0".

Here's a short snippet:
(hopefully I'm formatting this correctly)

(from default.aspx)

```
<%@ Register Src="Modules/StarRating.ascx" TagName="StarRating" TagPrefix="mytag" %>
```

(from StarRating.ascx)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="StarRating.ascx.cs" Inherits="StarRating" %>  
<h1>RATING: <%=OverallRating%></h1>
```

(from StarRating.ascx.cs)

```
public partial class StarRating : System.Web.UI.UserControl  
{  
    private int _OverallRating;  
    public string OverallRating  
    {  
        get { return _OverallRating.ToString(); }  
        set { _OverallRating = int.Parse(this.OverallRating); }  
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        Response.Write("RATING (from behind code!): " + OverallRating);  
        Response.Write("<BR />RATING (another one): " + _OverallRating);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the Markdown documentation, some simple instructions are on screen for you to read when you are editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OverallRating` set accessor, you're parsing the **current** value of the underlying integer variable instead of the value being passed to the property. This should fix it:

```
public string OverallRating  
{  
    get { return _OverallRating.ToString(); }  
    set { _OverallRating = int.Parse(value); }
}
```

(Presuming that wasn't just a typo)

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. I was using the variable too soon! Thanks very much :)